# What are the options for passing variables from AS2 swf to AS3 swf on AS3 button press?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface, actionscript-2, localconnection

I have 2 swfs, one image loader which I built a while ago and will eventually update to AS3 and a newer swf I built in AS3. I want to be able to 'pull' a variable from the AS2 swf when a button on the AS3 swf is pressed. How might i be able to do this. LocalConnection wont do it I dont think - i cant load the AS2 swf into the AS3 swf and obviously cant do the reverse though this would be the way to do it if it were possible.

So when a button in the AS3 swf is pressed I want to call the AS2 swf and return a variable from the AS2 swf (the filename of the current image). Would both swfs sharing ExternalInterface work?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LocalConnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html).  Or better yet: Use [SWFBridge](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html)

Comment: +1 for SWFBridge.  That is an absolute lifesaver in instances like these, and using it you absolutely can load the AS2 swf into the AS3 swf.

Comment: Note that LocalConnection may not be the most reliable. e.g. http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-371

Comment: @mj:That's why SWFBridge is better. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, LocalConnection may not be the most reliable: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-371

An alternative would be to do a combination of `fscommand()` and `ExternalInterface` via JavaScript.